# ajaxSetup, encoding and jQuery $.load() in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox, load

Using only the load - $.load(), carrying the contents of a page, and did not display the special characters.

I added the code:

```
$. ajaxSetup ({
'beforeSend': function (XHR) {
scriptCharset "iso-8859-1"
xhr.overrideMimeType ('application / x-www-form-urlencoded; charset = iso-8859-1');
}
});
```

Now it works perfectly in FireFox, but in Internet Explorer .... not.

How to work in Internet Explorer?
Ps: I'm not allowed to change the encoding (charset) of the original page, called via $. Load